# Building GIS apps from scratch?

Tags: gps, gis, android-gps

I am a very beginner in software and I am asking or a direction to proceed for research technologies to build my app. I am having just an idea for the app. I am trying to build something like zomato but different services. The idea of location based system is similar. I searched online and came to know about GIS systems. But while researching further, it seems I've to create a map all together. This feels redundant to build as we have api of google maps.
But can i use this api to build a system "ON" it????
Any tutorials or some direction in this direction would be helpful.
Also what is difference between GIS and gps based apps.
As you see, I am not very clear in the fundamentals of the GIS and GPS based apps

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Regarding Android, you have almost all you need by combining the [platform API](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/index.html) and the comprehensive [Google Maps Android API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api). Regarding the later, it's actually a matter of opting by convenience and possibly paying a licence fee to Google, versus developing your own solutions of aggregating free or cheaper services from elsewhere.

Most problems solved by apps are not the same problems solved by classical GIS software, since the former are more consumer-oriented (using public transportation, navigating a route, planning a trip, finding a nearby restaurant), and the later are more specialist-oriented, typically solving larger-scale and more technical issues (detecting regions with flood risk, monitoring deforestation, calculating volumes of terrain to be bulldozed, etc.)

You should not, IMO, be discouraged by the seemingly hard technical concepts of geography and map making. Your best bet is to have a clear vision of what actual problems you app should be solving, and study the geography topics gradually, as the need arises.

A bit of consideration on your question about GIS:

If it were created today, the GIS acronym would mean any software dealing with geographic data, be it a mobile app or a workstation software suite destined to specialized professional use.

But when it was created, the term meant almost exclusively the later sense, and so it has a lot of tradition and cultural legacy to it - which is of couse not always a good thing. Specifically (at least in my experience), it seems to me the jargon and concepts used by the classic GIS community are a bit impenetrable to the newcomer, specially if she comes from the software-development field instead of the geo-sciences field.

But geographic information availability has gone from scarcity to overwhelming abundance, and so have its enabling technologies: GPS satellites, mobile computing and mobile connectivity.